# How to fetch data from mongodb in kotlin?

Tags: database, mongodb, kotlin

I am trying to figure out how to simply fetch data from mongodb to kotlin so that I can perform aggregation pipeplines but I cant find any data or tutorials on how to do it. I have tried to write code to do so but cant figure out how to exactly do it, anyone got an idea?

A function that should fetch the data from mongodb:

```
fun main() {
    val client = getMongoClient()
    val database = client.getDatabase("<database>")
    val collection = database.getCollection("<collection>")

    val documents = fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection)

    for (document in documents) {
        println(document.toJson())
    }

    client.close()
}
```

Dependencies:

```
    // Mongo Realm
    implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.13.0")

    // Hilt
    implementation ("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")

    // Desugar JDK
    coreLibraryDesugaring ("com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:2.0.4")

    // Message Bar Compose
    implementation ("com.github.stevdza-san:MessageBarCompose:1.0.5")
```

By adding these 2 to pakaging it made the code runable:

```
excludes +="/META-INF/proguard/androidx-annotations.pro"
excludes += "META-INF/native-image/**"
```

Comment: Have you looked at MongoDB official documentation ? There's a [tutorial for Kotlin](https://www.mongodb.com/languages/kotlin). It also provides [a dedicated section on aggregations with Kotlin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/kotlin/coroutine/current/fundamentals/crud/read-operations/retrieve/#aggregate-operation). If this does not fit, can you add details to your question please (target platform -jvm, android, etc.-, What error you encounter, or what specific driver configuration blocks you, etc.) ?

Comment: Yes I have gone through quite a lot of tutorials and learnt how to use CRUD operations in mongoDb but cant find any turotials that describes how to fetch data from mongodb and then use it in aggregation @amanin

Comment: Platform: Android studio, kotlin language.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data from MongoDB in Kotlin, you can use the official MongoDB Kotlin driver. Here's a basic example of how you can fetch data from MongoDB and print the results:
First, make sure you have the MongoDB Kotlin driver added to your dependencies. You can add the following to your build.gradle.kts file:

```
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.4.0")
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-kotlin:1.8.1")
```

Then, you can create a function to fetch data from MongoDB using the Kotlin driver:

```
import org.bson.Document
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection
import com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates
import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters

fun getMongoClient(): com.mongodb.client.MongoClient {
    return MongoClients.create("<your-mongodb-connection-string>")
}

fun fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection: MongoCollection<Document>): List<Document> {
    // Define your aggregation pipeline stages here
    val pipeline = listOf(
        Aggregates.match(Filters.eq("fieldName", "fieldValue")),
        // Add more pipeline stages as needed
    )

    // Execute the aggregation pipeline
    val result = collection.aggregate(pipeline)

    // Convert the result to a list of documents
    val documents = mutableListOf<Document>()
    result.forEach { document ->
        documents.add(document)
    }

    return documents
}

fun main() {
    val client = getMongoClient()
    val database = client.getDatabase("<your-database>")
    val collection = database.getCollection("<your-collection>")

    val documents = fetchDataFromMongoDB(collection)

    for (document in documents) {
        println(document.toJson())
    }

    client.close()
}
```

Replace , , and  with your MongoDB connection string, database name, and collection name, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Hmm I have encountered an error when adding those 2 implementations saying: "2 files found with path 'META-INF/native-image/org.mongodb/bson/native-image.properties'.
Adding a packagingOptions block may help, please refer to
https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/8.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/ResourcesPackagingOptions
for more information"

Comment: Any idea as to why? @POTULA HARSHAVARDHAN

Comment: @JosefM Check your dependency tree — you may be pulling in two copies of the Mongo libraries.

Comment: I updated the question to include the mongoDb dependency but I only use 1 dependency. If i replace that 1 dependency with the other 2 I get error across the entire code, for example: realm not available, realminstant not working etc. @gidds

Comment: If i use these 2 combination:     implementation ("io.realm.kotlin:library-sync:1.13.0")
- implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.11.0"), that error with META-INF appears.

Comment: Get Gradle to print out the whole dependency tree: not just the dependencies you list, but _their_ dependencies, and _theirs_, etc. etc.  It's the only sure way to see what libraries you're actually getting.

Comment: hmm okej its done but how can I post it since it contains a lot of information?@gidds

Comment: hmm I added the following above to pakage option and it seems to have solved the error for now atleast. But still not sute on how to test and see if it is fetching data from mongodb to performe aggregation?@gidds

Comment: any idea? @gidds